# 3 finger swipe in Lion to change between .c and .h

Tags: xcode, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trackpad gesture to switch to header/source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771057/trackpad-gesture-to-switch-to-header-source)

How do you do this now in Lion? Doesn't work anymore after I upgraded and install the new XCode which is very annoying.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: You can enable that feature in Lion but you have to do some tweaking. You can find solution on this link https://gist.github.com/1132018

Answer (score 3):

I learned keyboard shortcut for Jump to next counterpart

> ctrl + cmd + up/down

Comment: ありがとう, I guess that'll have to do. :]

Comment: more information. I tried this solution and it has work! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771057/trackpad-gesture-to-switch-to-header-source/7923619#7923619