# Trackpad gesture to switch to header/source

Tags: macos, xcode4, osx-lion

I used to be able to use three finger scroll-up to switch between source/header.  Since upgrading to Lion, I it just does a regular scroll.  Is there any way to get that feature back?

Aka, it doesn't jump to counterpart when I scroll up / down like it used to.

### Update

Apple fixed the issue in Xcode 4.2.  So, upgrade your versions.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. I think this is because of Mission Control gesture which is set on three finger swipe-up. But even if I have changed it to be four finger swipe-up, xcode does not recognise/receive that one.

Comment: I found the fix to this issue here: https://gist.github.com/1132018

Comment: Buyin's fix indeed does work. Follow the directions right here: gist.github.com/1132018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple fixed the issue in Xcode 4.2. So, upgrade your versions.

Have fun coding and mind the occasional crash.

Comment: It's four-fingers up or down now.

Comment: @erikprice that just starts mission control for me.  It's still 3 up/down.

Comment: Weird, for me mission control is 3 up. I just noticed the 4 up/down recently, so maybe it came with some software update or other.

Comment: @erikprice That's because you have it set up that way :)  System Preferences->Trackpad->More Gestures->Mission Control (you can select 3 or 4 fingers).

Comment: I'm running 4.2.1 and this gesture doesn't work, even if I switch mission control, etc, to four fingers in prefs.

Comment: I got this to work with Xcode 4.2 or 4.3 but I had to set the "switch between pages" gesture to 3 fingers. Which I don't like. I'm looking for a way to key 2 finger navigation with the three finger up/down gesture for switching .h and .m files.

Answer (score 25):

[This is the correct and best answer](https://gist.github.com/1132018). It works. It is posted by "@Buyin" above. Another individual commented that it doesn't work. He is wrong. It works, I've confirmed it. It restores the three finger vertical swipe to switch between interface and implementation files (.h and .m) in xCode in Lion.

From your terminal:

Change to appropriate directory (note, if your Library dir is hidden, in the terminal just type the following: chflags nohidden ~/Library )

```
1. cd /Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Preferences/ByHost
```

List files so you can see the .GlobalPreferences.XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX.plist

```
2. ls -lah
```

Open that plist file in xcode

```
3. open -a /Applications/Xcode.app ".GlobalPreferences.XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX.plist"
```

Set value to 1 for the key "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerVertSwipeGesture"

Save the plist file

Log out and back into machine

VOILA!

Comment: Yep, it works. Nice to have that gesture back. And now I take it you will bring this oversight "to Apple's attention so they can fix it"?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. (Of course it works for YOU, but there's a step missing somewhere, some setting that is different for "us unfortunate people".) Saying "he is wrong" is, well, wrong. *shrug*

Comment: Kalle, did you follow the steps, and what doesn't work, specifically. What step did you get stuck at? Did you shut down Xcode first. Did you find the .GlobalPreferences plist file? Did you set the key 'com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerVertSwipeGesture to '1'?

Comment: Thank you. Works for me. Also a log out/ login works instead of a restart.

Comment: I think it's important to add that Terminal wouldn't navigate to that directory in my case, but showing hidden files and using the "Go" menu of Finder did work.

Comment: I had to make a few changes... Firstly, my Xcode.app was downloaded from the App Store and so the path had to be updated to `open -a /Applications/Xcode.app`. Also, there were 4 files with the `.GlobalPreferences` prefix, and since I didn't know which one to change, I ended up changing all four. And lastly (as @SteveMoser writes above), you don't have to restart the machine, simply logging out of your user account and logging back in will suffice.

Comment: I updated the answer above to account for changes to the directory of Xcode since Xcode is now in new dir from app store. Thanks to "jowie" for your comment with this info...

Comment: For those who this isn't working for: do you have a magic trackpad? This answer did it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9985510/677620

Answer (score 10):

Given apple took this away (hopefully just for now) the only way I can think of to get this working again would be to install BetterTouchTool[1] and bind the keyboard control - control-cmd-up, ctrl-cmd-down - to the three finger motion. You'd also have to switch the default three finger motion in sys prefs to use four fingers for mission control.

[1] http://blog.boastr.net/

Comment: Not a good solution since it would also send the same command to non-XCode apps.  I'll just wait for Apple to fix it.

Comment: I believe it's possible with BTT to bind to a specific app, but I agree it would be better if apple would just fix it :)

Comment: BetterTouchTool is a great little App! Fixed the XCode problem for me.

Comment: I started using BetterTouchTool when I got a magic trackpad because unlike the laptops trackpad, the above fixes weren't working. I still need to try medTechy's solution above which probably takes care of it, then I won't have to have BTT on.

Answer (score 10):

As found in internet:

```
defaults -currentHost write -g "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerVertSwipeGesture" -int 1
```

> Logout and Login again

Comment: This also works for Xcode 5 running under Mavericks FYI.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using an Apple magic trackpad, you'll also need to edit

```
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist
```

which can be found in the

```
/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Preferences
```

directory.  Open it and change the **threeFingerVertSwipeGesture** key to a **1**.

Save the *.plist

I also changed both my App Expose and Mission Control swipes to be 4 finder swipes instead of Lion's default 3 finger swipe.

Restart your computer

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from icnivad was so very close to working for me. With one additional step.

From your terminal:

Change to appropriate directory (note, if your Library dir is hidden, in the terminal just type the following: chflags nohidden ~/Library )

```
1. cd /Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Preferences/ByHost
```

List files so you can see the .GlobalPreferences.XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX.plist

```
2. ls -lah
```

Open that plist file in xcode

```
3. open -a /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app ".GlobalPreferences.XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX.plist"
```

Set value to 1 for the key "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerVertSwipeGesture"

Save the plist file

Restart machine

THEN

Make sure the "Three finger drag" System Preference is disabled. This seems to take precedence and stop the Xcode gesture from working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can now switch using a left and right two finger swipe.  Seems pretty buggy though, given that this also scrolls the screen.  It also switches the butler from automatic to manual mode.

I'm starting to hate the combination of Lion and Xcode.

Comment: This doesn't toggle between header and implementation files, it's the equivalent of pressing the back & forward buttons. Still useful, though.

Comment: That's interesting, Andrew.  It definitely switches between the header and implementation for me.  It still seems very unnatural to me.

Comment: This is not a fix, but a lousy workaround. What people are looking for is the vertical three finger swipe that we once had and loved before lion/xcode removed it.

Answer (score 1):

This stopped working for me in MacOS Big Sur and the plist changes recommended here didn't fix it for me.

What finally fixed it for me was to go to

System Preferences > Trackpad > More Gestures

and change the setting for "Swipe between pages" to "Swipe with two or three fingers". I suspect setting it to "Swipe with three fingers" would also work.

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason Apple removed the h/m 3-finger swipe is because they expect you to use the "Assistant" editor, which displays the h and m files together, side by side.
This works, sort of, on a wide screen, although it is an inefficient use of space. But when you're on the road with a MacBookAir, it's a major handicap.
Xcode4 feels like a straitjacket.

Comment: I'm always typing anyway so it's easier and faster to use the keyboard shortcut than the mouse. I'd say YMMV but it's Xcode, what are you doing if not typing when you want to switch between the header and implementation?

Comment: I use Xcode 4 on my MacBook Air (11") and the Assistant works fine for me, and I still miss three-finger swipe for the times that I wanted to switch the main editor over to implementation in preparation to open something else (a nib or another class) in the assistant editor.

Comment: nope, this is not correct. they don't expect you to use the assistant editor instead. It appears to be an oversight and needs to be brought to Apple's attention so they can fix it.