# Xcode 4.1 three finger swipe to switch from .m to .h?

Tags: xcode4, osx-lion

How can I re-enable this in Lion? I know the keyboard shortcut, but the gesture was much more practical.

Comment: From everything I've read it's no longer around, and the suggestion is to file a bug to apple

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771057/trackpad-gesture-to-switch-to-header-source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771057/trackpad-gesture-to-switch-to-header-source/7923619#7923619)

You get the three finger vertical swipe back in xcode on lion!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way around this so i went to the keyboard solution CTRL+COMMAND+UP

Answer (score 1):

You can also do ALT+CMD+Carriage Return. That will give you the assistant editor with the counterpart file alongside.

CMD+Carriage Return will reverse that, showing you just the standard editor again.

Answer (score 1):

If someone comes across this with MacOS Big Sur, go to

System Preferences > Trackpad > More Gestures

and change the setting for "Swipe between pages" to either "Swipe with two or three fingers" or "Swipe with three fingers"

Answer (score 0):

Try that: System Preferences -> Trackpad, and then disable anything related to 3-finger swap.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the terminal, after this logout and login again.

```
defaults -currentHost write -g "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerVertSwipeGesture" -int 1
```