# Control-Command-Up not switching to counterpart file in Xcode on Lion.

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion

Since the [three finger swipe has been stolen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771057/trackpad-gesture-to-switch-to-header-source) in Lion, I find myself forced to resort to the keyboard to switch between .h and .m files.  Two finger swipe left and right only seems to work infrequently, and that should be for scrolling anyways.

The keyboard command should be Control-Command-Up, but for some reason this takes me out of Xcode and shows the project file in Finder.

I have checked both System Preferences, and Xcode's key bindings settings, and I can't find anything wrong.  Xcode is set properly, and I can't find any conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug.  For now I assigned another key combination: ^Q and ^Z to "jump to counterpart" and it works.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but with different keys.

Answer (score 27):

Do you by any chance have another program such as Afloat installed that might be taking over the key combination? For instance, Afloat uses the Control-Command-Up key combo to do just what you described - show the open application's file in Finder.

Besides changing the key combo, the Xcode default Control-Command-Down will also switch to the counterpart.

Comment: This was what was causing it for me. You can disable Afloat for Xcode with the following terminal command "defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AfloatDisableForThisApp -bool yes"

Comment: Definitely the last place I would have looked for this solution.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 Another frustrated developer giving you even more kudos! :)

Comment: It helped for a few minutes, but now its doing the same. Anything else that could help ?

Comment: In my case, I was using an application called SizeUp that hijacked those Xcode key combinations for "Send Window Space Above" and "Send Window Space Below"... disabling those in SizeUp's preferences restored Xcode's "View Counterpart" functionality.