# How can I change Xcode 4.4.1's 3-finger multitouch select action within an editor?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.4

Xcode 4.2 used to toggle between the header file and the .m file when you swiped up/down with 3 fingers in an editor window.  Now excode 4.4.1 turns it into a text selection.  Is there a way to change the default behavior to something else (in my case back to toggling between .h/.m)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to change the gesture within Xcode, but usually i find if i open .h first, then .m (or the other way around) then you can swipe between them with 2 fingers right or left :)

As long as you open them in the centre and not in a new window =]

Comment: I know, it's not perfect, but at least it's easier :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the 3 finger swipe working in Xcode 4.4 (I'm running Mountain Lion). It is possible. Try following these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7923619/472344.

I had already used these to get the 3 finger swipe working in Xcode 4.3 when I updated to Lion. It seemed to break when I updated to Xcode 4.4 and Mountain Lion. I went through all the steps again, but this time all the settings were already set correctly so I didn't have to change anything. However, now it's working for me. Give it a shot.

You can also switch between the .h and .m by using ctrl+command+UpArrow (or DownArrow).